# AttributeError: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'metadata' from ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro, metadata, attributeerror

I am trying to get the metadata for each layer within each map within a ArcGIS Pro project (.aprx file), but get this error message: `AttributeError: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'metadata'`. The code is simple:

```
import arcpy
project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"path\to\project.aprx")
maps = project.listMaps()
for map in maps:
    print(map.name)
    layers = map.listLayers()
    for layer in layers:
        print("  " + layer.name)
        print("    " + layer.metadata.description)
```

I did not really see how this is different with the 4th code block at https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/metadata/metadata-class.htm.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to use a property that only became available in versions later than ArcGIS Pro 2.4.

When I run the code below:

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\temp\Projects\TestProject\TestProject.aprx")
mapx = aprx.listMaps()[0]
print(mapx.name)
lyr = mapx.listLayers()[0]
print(lyr.name)
print(lyr.metadata.description)
```

it reports:

```
Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May 20 2020, 01:49:13) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
========================== RESTART: C:\temp\test.py ==========================
Map
TestPoly
None
>>>
```

In this instance I am not sure why `metadata.description` is reporting as `None` because I have given that layer (and its underlying feature class) what I believe are valid values.  In any event, my version (which is later than ArcGIS Pro 2.4) does recognise the `metadata` property of the layer which your version 2.4 does not.

When I run this code in the Python window of the same project I do see the expected output:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
layer = aprx.listMaps()[0].listLayers()[0]
layer_metadata = layer.metadata
print(layer_metadata.title)
print(layer_metadata.description)
TestPoly
<DIV STYLE="text-align:Left;"><DIV><DIV><P><SPAN STYLE="font-size:12pt">This is my test description that I added from the Catalog pane by right-clicking on the feature class and choosing Edit Metadata.  I then copied the metadata from the feature class to a layer created from it using the Metadata tab of the Layer Properties.</SPAN></P></DIV></DIV></DIV>
```

---

I reported the above to Esri, and they said:

> It is currently a known issue and the metadata team is working on a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is to do with *which* metadata you are accessing. Study your code you are accessing the metadata from what? A layer, but how did you get a handle on that...from the map document. You are not accessing the metadata of the *dataset* but a layer object in a map.

If you go to the properties of the layer and change the dialog to *layer has own metadata*, then you code will run without error.

[image: Layer properties dialog]

This confusion in what metadata you are actually looking at is a downside of ArcGIS Pro. In ArcMap this layer information was simply referred to as the layer description and is a property of a layer object not a dataset object. In ArcGIS Pro they have confused things by referring to this layer property as metadata which in the classic sense is something associated with the base dataset.